# Open system recovery causes bluescreen 0x00000050 with ntfs.sys

Tags: windows-7, system-restore, volume-shadow-copy

Since yesterday my computer crashes with a bluescreen 0x00000050 as soon as I do something with the system restore.
For example (tried to translate from german to english so the exact programname could be different):

- Windows system settings/System and Safety/System/Computersafety and
  when I try to change to  the tab Computersafety it gives me the
  bluescreen.
- CCleaner->Tools/Systemrestore - shows me the new tab short but
  without a restore point but results after 1-2 seconds in the same
  bluescreen
- Cobian Backup Boletus-> Start a backup task with the enabled option
  "Use Volume Shadow Copy" results with this bluescreen.
- Leaving the computer for some minutes in idle results in a bluescreen
  (maybe the system tries to create a resore point or the cobian
  backup starts or something like this)
- Installing a new driver results in a bluescreen because it tries to
  create a new restore point before installing the driver

The harddisk is checked with `chkdsk` and it found no errors. Ram is checked with Memtest+ without any error.

Minidump result:

```
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA (50)
Invalid system memory was referenced.  This cannot be protected by try-except,
it must be protected by a Probe.  Typically the address is just plain bad or it
is pointing at freed memory.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff981155026a8, memory referenced.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation.
Arg3: fffff8800121a460, If non-zero, the instruction address which referenced the bad memory address.
Arg4: 0000000000000005, (reserved)

Debugging Details:
------------------


Could not read faulting driver name

READ_ADDRESS: GetPointerFromAddress: unable to read from fffff80002eba100
 fffff981155026a8 

FAULTING_IP: 
Ntfs!memmove+250
fffff880`0121a460 488b440af8      mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx+rcx-8]

MM_INTERNAL_CODE:  5

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x50

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff88002fa3d60 -- (.trap 0xfffff88002fa3d60)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000020 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=fffff981155026d8
rdx=ffffffffffffffd8 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff8800121a460 rsp=fffff88002fa3ef8 rbp=fffff98015502728
 r8=00000000ffffff68  r9=0000000007fffffb r10=0000000000000001
r11=fffff98015502770 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
Ntfs!memmove+0x250:
fffff880`0121a460 488b440af8      mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx+rcx-8] ds:fffff981`155026a8=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002c323bf to fffff80002c87c40

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`02fa3bf8 fffff800`02c323bf : 00000000`00000050 fffff981`155026a8 00000000`00000000 fffff880`02fa3d60 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`02fa3c00 fffff800`02c85d6e : 00000000`00000000 fffff981`155026a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000028 : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x44791
fffff880`02fa3d60 fffff880`0121a460 : fffff880`012a65a8 00000000`00000028 fffff880`02fa3f50 fffff8a0`00000400 : nt!KiPageFault+0x16e
fffff880`02fa3ef8 fffff880`012a65a8 : 00000000`00000028 fffff880`02fa3f50 fffff8a0`00000400 00000000`00000001 : Ntfs!memmove+0x250
fffff880`02fa3f00 fffff880`012a6740 : fffff8a0`03103070 fffff800`02e28260 fffff8a0`03103070 fffff980`15502400 : Ntfs!NtfsRestartInsertSimpleRoot+0x50
fffff880`02fa3f40 fffff880`012caa2f : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffffa80`025f3180 fffff880`02fa40d8 fffff880`02fa4110 : Ntfs!InsertSimpleRoot+0xb8
fffff880`02fa4010 fffff880`01281d3b : 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`03103070 fffff880`02fa40d8 fffff880`02fa4168 : Ntfs!AddToIndex+0xcf
fffff880`02fa4090 fffff880`0129dda5 : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffff8a0`03103070 fffff8a0`0d7e8518 fffffa80`00000000 : Ntfs!NtOfsAddRecords+0x167
fffff880`02fa4270 fffff880`012ce520 : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffff8a0`0d7e8510 00000000`0008a0fc 00000000`0008a100 : Ntfs!GetSecurityIdFromSecurityDescriptorUnsafe+0x1fd
fffff880`02fa4320 fffff880`0127d532 : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffffa80`025f3180 00000000`00000000 fffff980`15502d00 : Ntfs!NtfsCacheSharedSecurityByDescriptor+0xa0
fffff880`02fa4370 fffff880`012955ed : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffffa80`025f3180 fffff800`02e28260 00000000`00000000 : Ntfs! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x11530
fffff880`02fa43f0 fffff880`01228b0c : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffff880`01252a00 fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffff8a0`0a0c1010 : Ntfs!NtfsUpdateFcbInfoFromDisk+0x4fe
fffff880`02fa4540 fffff880`012f3592 : fffffa80`01b4fd40 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff8a0`0a0c1010 : Ntfs!NtfsInitializeDirectory+0x254
fffff880`02fa4650 fffff880`012ed3fa : fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffffa80`025f3180 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`025f3180 : Ntfs!NtfsInitializeExtendDirectory+0x3d6
fffff880`02fa4810 fffff880`0128880d : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`024e4010 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : Ntfs!NtfsMountVolume+0x1691
fffff880`02fa4b50 fffff880`0120f985 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`01b4fd40 fffff800`02c8ff93 : Ntfs!NtfsCommonFileSystemControl+0x59
fffff880`02fa4b90 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : Ntfs!NtfsFspDispatch+0x2ad


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
Ntfs!memmove+250
fffff880`0121a460 488b440af8      mov     rax,qword ptr [rdx+rcx-8]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  Ntfs!memmove+250

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: Ntfs

IMAGE_NAME:  Ntfs.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4d79997b

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_Ntfs!memmove+250

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0x50_Ntfs!memmove+250

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

I disabled the Cobian backup program and disabled the system restore with the help of Windows PowerShell (disable-computerrestore -drive "C:\") and everything works fine for now. But I want the system restore/volume shadow copy back. What can I do?

**Operating system is Windows 7 Professional 64bit.**

Screenshot of NirSoft BlueScreenView:

[image: NirSoft BlueScreenView]

I managed to [solve this question myself](https://superuser.com/a/541527/16858).

Comment: I could not answer my own questions at this time because I had to less points or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there was a problem with some of the automatic created restore point files. I booted with Knoppix and removed everything from "System Volume Information" to a backup directory so I had a empty "System Volume Information" folder. Reboot to Windows and everything is working fine again with the System Volume Shadow service and the system restore.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation, I solved the problem by doing a clean reinstallation of Win 7:

I downloaded the Knoppix CD (not the DVD version, as I just wanted to boot to Linux) and deleted the `SYSTEM VOLUME INFORMATION` directory.

I recreated the same volume, so it was present in Windows after the reboot.
I then rebooted WIN 7 and created a new restore point.
As a test, I restored to this point and it all worked fine.